# Django - how to dynamically generate a menu in base template

Tags: django

I want to dynamically generate a menu from the database, and separate this menu into a template base.html. I dynamically generated the menu Html in home's view.py, and then output this html to base.html. However, I can only display the menu when I visit the Home page, but not when I jump to another page. How can I display the menu on each page?

**home/view.py**

```
    def dashboard(request):
        """
        :param request:
        :return:
        """
        if 'user_id' not in request.session:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('login')

        menus = load_nav(request)
        context = {'menus': menus, 'username': request.session.get('user_name')}
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)

     def load_nav(request):
        """
        :param request:
        :return: 
        """
        current_user = User.objects.get(id=request.session.get('user_id'))
        if current_user is None:
            return render(request, './unauthorized.html')
        try:
            current_user_role = current_user.role.all()[:1].get()
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return render(request, './unauthorized.html', {'message': 'No Auth.'})

        menus = current_user_role.nav.filter(parent=None).all()
        sub_menus = current_user_role.nav.exclude(parent__isnull=True).all()

        menu_html = ''
        if menus is None:
            menu_html += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Index</a>'
        else:
            for menu in menus:
                if not menu.hasChildNav():
                    menu_html += '<li><a href="{url}" target="{target}"><i class="icon {icon}"></i><span>{name}</span></a>'
                else:
                    menu_html += '<li class="submenu"><a href="#" target="{target}"><i class="icon {icon}"></i><span>{name}</span></a>'
                    menu_html += '<ul style="display: none;">'
                    menu_html += load_sub_nav(menu.id, sub_menus)
                    menu_html += '</ul>'
                menu_html = menu_html.format(url=menu.url, icon=menu.icon, target=menu.target, name=menu.name)
        return format_html(menu_html)


    def load_sub_nav(parent_id, menu):
        """
        :param parent_id: 
        :param menu: 
        :return: 
        """
        sub_menu_html = ''
        sub_menus = menu.filter(parent=parent_id).all()
        if sub_menus is not None:
            for sub_menu in sub_menus:
                if not sub_menu.hasChildNav():
                    sub_menu_html += '<li><a href="{url}" target="{target}"><i class="icon {icon}" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i>' \
                                     '<span style="padding-left: 10px;">{name}</span></a></li>'
                else:
                    sub_menu_html += '<li clas="submenu"><a href="#" target="{target}"><i class="icon {icon}" style="padding-left: 15px;"></i>' \
                                     '<span style="padding-left: 10px;">{name}</span></a></li>'
                    sub_menu_html += '<ul>'
                    sub_menu_html += load_sub_nav(sub_menu.parent, sub_menus)
                    sub_menu_html += '</ul>'
                sub_menu_html = sub_menu_html.format(url=sub_menu.url, icon=sub_menu.icon, target=sub_menu.target, name=sub_menu.name)
        return format_html(sub_menu_html)

****base.html:****
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block css %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--sidebar-menu-->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                {% block navbar %}

                    {{ menus }}

                {% endblock %}
            </ul>
            <!--sidebar-menu-->
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: i want to dynamically generate a menu in template(base.html), and there two pages(home/index.html; user/index.html) extends it(base.html)，but now, the menu just show in home/index.html, the user/index.html can not show the menu. 
How to make all inherited pages show dynamically generated menu？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your base templates in the others. So ideally you put this line as first line in the index.html files:

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Comment: i have include the base.html in index.html, and then can show the menu in index.html, but when i include base.html in setting.html, it can not show the menu.
index.html：# can be work
{% extends 'base.html' %}

setting.html: # can not work
{% extends 'base.html' %}

Comment: Can you show the view function you use to show setting.html

Answer (score 0):

In my own project I created a file called 'context_processors.py'. In that file I created a method that returns the context data for the navigation bar.

```
def navbar_context(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'categories': categories}
```

Add this to your settings.py in the TEMPLATES list.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],  # get templates from the root directory
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            # context processor for dynamic navbar content i.e. Products dropdown menu
            'shop.context_processors.navbar_context',
        ],
    },
},
```

]